# Is a subalgebra of $\mathcal L(X)$ whose commutant is $Z(\mathcal L(X))$ necessarily equal to $\mathcal L(X)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Main question:**

Let $X$ be a $\mathbb K$-vector space with $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Let $\mathcal L(X)$ be the set of continous linear applications from $X$ to $X$.
Let $\mathcal A$ be a subalgebra of $\mathcal L(X)$ such that
$$\{b\in\mathcal L(X)\,|\,\forall a\in\mathcal A,\,ab=ba\}=\{\lambda I\,|\,\lambda\in\mathbb K\}\,.$$

I am expecting the following result (but do not know how to prove it).

- **Assume $X$ is finite dimensional. Then $\mathcal A=\mathcal L(X)$.**

I doubt this is a very original question, could someone indicate me a method to solve this problem?

---

**Some possible extensions:**

If it is indeed the case:

1. Can we generalize this result to the case of $X$ a Hilbert space, i.e. $\overline {\mathcal A}=\mathcal L(X)$ for some topology to be precised on $\mathcal L(X)$?
2. Same thing for $X$ a Banach space.
3. And if we replace $\mathcal L(X)$ by a Banach algebra with unity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition you impose on $\mathcal A$ is that its *commutant* $\mathcal A'$ is trivial.

In the generality you are asking, the result is not true: for example, let
$$
A=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&c \end{bmatrix}:\ a,b,c\in\mathbb K \right\}\subset\mathcal L(\mathbb K^2).
$$
Then $\mathcal A'=\mathbb K\,I$.

Your claim does hold, though, when $\mathcal A$ is a *selfadjoint* algebra (i.e. contains adjoints of its elements, or transposes if $\mathbb K=\mathbb R$). What you are then looking for is von Neumann Double Commutant Theorem:

> If $H$ is a Hilbert space, and $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal L(H)$ is a non-degenerate selfadjoint subalgebra,
>   $$
> \mathcal A''=\overline{\mathcal A}^{\rm SOT}
> $$
>   where SOT is the *strong operator topology* (i.e. pointwise convergence). Other topologies satisfy the equality too.

In the finite-dimensional case, it is easy to see that any selfadjoint subalgebra is closed in the pointwise topology.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.